# MYSQL 5 Creating an envelope around points stored in a column

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-query

I'm Marc and new to coding and databases. For my study I need to create a table with geographical data, collected by gps. This needs to be done in **mysql 5**. Importing the measurements from .csv, I came up with the following table:

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| meting_nr | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | 0       |       | 
| y_coord   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| x_coord   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| height    | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| type      | char(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| type_nr   | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| pt        | point    | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I determined the minimum and the maximum coordinates using the following query;

```
select meting_nr, astext(pt) from gps where (x_coord = (select min(x_coord) from gps)) or (x_coord = (select max(x_coord) from gps)) or (y_coord = (select min(y_coord) from gps)) or (y_coord = (select max(y_coord) from gps));
```

this results in the following points:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| meting_nr | astext(pt)                     |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
|       101 | POINT(138235.3123 452751.2959) | 
|       104 | POINT(138238.6632 452749.3718) | 
|       161 | POINT(138207.704 452714.8049)  | 
|       190 | POINT(138197.9728 452715.1304) | 
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

I want a MBR around ALL these points. With following query I get a MBR around each seperate point:

```
select meting_nr, astext(envelope(pt)) from gps where (x_coord = (select min(x_coord) from gps)) or (x_coord = (select max(x_coord) from gps)) or (y_coord = (select min(y_coord) from gps)) or (y_coord = (select max(y_coord) from gps));
```

resulting in:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| meting_nr | astext(envelope(pt))                                                                                                               |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       101 | POLYGON((138235.3123 452751.2959,138235.3123 452751.2959,138235.3123 452751.2959,138235.3123 452751.2959,138235.3123 452751.2959)) | 
|       104 | POLYGON((138238.6632 452749.3718,138238.6632 452749.3718,138238.6632 452749.3718,138238.6632 452749.3718,138238.6632 452749.3718)) | 
|       161 | POLYGON((138207.704 452714.8049,138207.704 452714.8049,138207.704 452714.8049,138207.704 452714.8049,138207.704 452714.8049))      | 
|       190 | POLYGON((138197.9728 452715.1304,138197.9728 452715.1304,138197.9728 452715.1304,138197.9728 452715.1304,138197.9728 452715.1304)) | 
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What where you expecting to see ?

Comment: Also.... Envelope() is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use ST_Envelope() instead.   it's in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_envelope)

Comment: I was expecting to see a mbr that covers ALL the points, not a separate one for every point And I understand the use of ST_envelope, but I have to work with mysql 5.0

Comment: fair enough, i don't have time to fully research this as i need to go for a few hours .. but mine best guess is to pack those `POINT` records into a MultiPoint/MultiPolygon Class to run `envelope()` on to get the MBR..